# QgsVectorLayer as processing output in QGIS3

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3

I would like to create a QgsVectorLayer using memory in a python script that will run in a processing model. Using the doc provided here https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/user_manual/processing/scripts.html I created the following script. However, the output layer is not loaded in QGIS and not even saved in a file.

```py
from qgis import processing
from qgis.processing import alg
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.PyQt.QtCore import QVariant

@alg(name='test', label="test", group='examplescripts', group_label='Example scripts')
@alg.input(type=alg.VECTOR_LAYER_DEST, name='OUTPUT',
           label='output')
def test(instance, parameters, context, feedback, inputs):
    """
    Description of the algorithm.
    (If there is no comment here, you will get an error)
    """

    vl = QgsVectorLayer("Point", "test", "memory")
    pr = vl.dataProvider()
    pr.addAttributes([QgsField("name", QVariant.String),
                      QgsField("age",  QVariant.Int),
                      QgsField("size", QVariant.Double)])
    vl.updateFields() 

    f = QgsFeature()
    f.setGeometry(QgsGeometry.fromPointXY(QgsPointXY(10,10)))
    f.setAttributes(["Ada L.", 2, 0.3])
    pr.addFeature(f)
    vl.updateExtents() 

    return {'OUTPUT': vl}
```

Tried other return options, but no success

```
return {'OUTPUT': vl.id()}
return vl
```

Checking the docs there is `QgsFeatureSink` class, like in this code https://gist.github.com/ghtmtt/cd6ee99f69ce87298f9eb3466129306f. However, I'm not sure how to reach to this object using the function parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Your variable `vl` is a layer in memory. You haven't actually saved it to the output directory yet - `return {'OUTPUT': vl}` is ultimately a console return, something completely separate from your pre-defined OUTPUT variable.

One option, and likely the most widely accepted, is to use QgsVectorFileWriter like in [this question/reply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58818951/15738882).
Another would be, if you use any `processing.run()` algorithms; they tend to have the actual saving of the file implemented meaning you can pass the file output path on to those.
I have personally never worked with QgsFeatureSink before. I know it should have some of the functionality you are looking for, but someone else would have to explain how that works exactly.